# SQL - "ON DUPLICATE KEY" with an auto-incrementing primary key & no unique ID's?

Tags: mysql, innodb

My script needs to update the `lastVisited` field for the given user, but IF the row doesn't exist yet I obviously have to insert the whole row. Problem is, the `id` column is auto-incrementing and I have no way of knowing what the next value will be. The other columns are not unique on their own, BUT `studentId` and `classId` are unique as pairs and I know both of their values when I'm running the script, so how do I pair them up in my SQL statement? I was excited to learn about `ON DUPLICATE KEY` but that'll only work if I can somehow pair up the two known columns. Ideas?

Comment: If the ID column is auto-incrementing, and you want the last tuple, surely you can use the SQL `MAX` function to get the last row?

Comment: Cheched this? => http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

Comment: I think that a procedure may be the optimal solution here.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I assume you're right but I have no idea what a procedure means here... Could you or someone else write a procedure for this? I'm searching around for info on this but haven't found an example that's close enough for me to understand how it pertains to my problem.

Comment: @tylerl We do not write code here. We can help you with errors in code. What you want to search for is a procedure that will perform and insert or update depending on whether a record exists.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO fair enough, I just didn't want to write horribly inefficient SQL statements... Thanks for the help